# mem_set for std::map or std::list

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, stl

Can we do a `mem_set()` for `std::map` or `std::list` as soon as we create them. For ex,

```
typedef std::map<int, double> MY_MAP;
typedef std::list<int> MY_LIST;
MY_MAP *map_obj = new MY_MAP();
mem_set(map_obj, 0, sizeof(MY_MAP));
MY_LIST mylist;
mem_set(&mylist, 0, sizeof(MY_LIST));
```

and I continue with normal stl operations

```
map_obj->insert(std::make_pair<int, double> (1, 2.2));
mylist.push_back(1);
```

Is it correct to perform a `mem_set()`, and if it is correct can I do similarly for other STL c++ containers like `std::vector`, `std::set` etc

What will happen if we do a `mem_set()` to stl containers internally?

Comment: There's no point in trying to zero out the contents of a new map or list, since they don't *have* any contents yet.

Comment: `mem_set`? Do you mean `memset`?

Comment: I'd recommend to never do that (see the 'undefined behavior' comments). Remove the `new`s and the `memset`s, and your code should be ok. You might not want to use `MY_MAP::insert` at first as well, just the `operator[]`

Comment: That would be nonsense, of course. Why do you want to do that? What effects do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

What you propose is undefined behaviour, and given the popular implementations of the standard library it has zero chance to do anything useful even by accident.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we do a mem_set() for std::map or std::list [...?]

No. `std::map` and `std::list` are families of non-[POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) types. You are not supposed to mess with their internal representations on this low level. Apart from being UB, you would very likely violate the type's internal invariants. The same is true for `std::string`.

However, the default constructors of these types already create objects in a kind of "zero state". That is, they will be "empty" / will not contain any elements.

> Is it correct to perform a mem_set()

No.

> What will happen if we do a mem_set() to stl containers internally?

Nothing good. These types are non-PODs for a reason. They have "private parts" that nobody should mess with directly on that level.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish?

When you call `new MY_MAP();`, it allocates memory for the map *and* runs the constructor. That puts the map into a known, valid state. By calling `men_set` (*memset*?) you are setting everything in the map to zero, almost certainly leaving the map in some invalid state. Inserting things into this map will fail, hopefully sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for my question above came from the following implementation.

```
MY_STRUCT *new_struct = new MY_STRUCT;
memset(new_struct,0,sizeof(MY_STRUCT));
```

This would perfectly work fine as soon as the structure is defined like

```
struct my_struct{
int a;
double b[100];
}MY_STRUCT;
```

But if the structure is defined as following

```
struct my_struct{
int a;
double b[100];
std::map<int,double> my_map;
std::vector<int> my_vector;
}MY_STRUCT;
```

doing a memset() for the above structure would try to initialize even the map and vector, 
so is it allowed to do a memset() to a struct object if they contains STL containers?

Comment: I guess your last sentence was supposed to be a question. If so, the answer is "No!".